# Creating and Saving Access Tokens simplejwt Django

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, axios, django-rest-auth, django-rest-framework-simplejwt

I've been following this tutorial:https://medium.com/@gerrysabar/implementing-google-login-with-jwt-in-django-for-restful-api-authentication-eaa92e50522d to try and implement a google based login from my front end, so far everything works in terms of the creating the account based on the google token and then creating the token using RefreshToken.for_user(). However, I tried testing my application by making a very simple view to test it via the permission classes as below:

```
class VerifyAuthView(APIView):
    permission_classes = (IsAuthenticated,)
    def post(self,request):
        return Response({"status":"true"})
```

I get returned a 401 error when I try and access this.
I have a couple ideas what it might be such as:

- I have noticed in the django admin panel under tokens there is none listed even immediately after creation, maybe the token is only being generated and not saving although I can't work out why
- I've seen a couple of people say it could be to do with rest_framework permissions classes, although changing these hasn't helped so far

My Views.py (also contains my VerifyAuthView as above):

```
from django.contrib.auth.base_user import BaseUserManager
from django.contrib.auth.hashers import make_password
from rest_framework.utils import json
from rest_framework.views import APIView,status
from rest_framework.response import Response
import requests
from rest_framework_simplejwt.tokens import RefreshToken
from django.contrib.auth.models import User


class GoogleView(APIView):
    def post(self,request):
        payload = {'access_token':request.data.get("access_token")} #validating token
        req = requests.get('https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v2/userinfo',params= payload)
        data = json.loads(req.text)

        if 'error' in data:
            content = {'message': 'Invalid Google Token'}
            return Response(content)
        email = data['email']     

        #check if user has authenticated before or not
        try:
            user = User.objects.get(email=data['email'])

        except User.DoesNotExist:
            #Create user if they have not logged in before
            user = User()
            user.username = data['email']
            user.password = make_password(BaseUserManager().make_random_password())
            user.email = data['email']
            user.save()

        #Creating access token for user
        token = RefreshToken.for_user(user)
        response = {}
        response['username'] = user.username
        response['access_token'] = str(token.access_token)
        response['refresh_token'] = str(token)

        return Response(response)
```

And in my settings.py my rest_framework attribute is set up as follows:

```
CORS_ORIGIN_ALLOW_ALL = True

REST_FRAMEWORK = {
    'DEFAULT_PERMISSION_CLASSES':[
    #for demo purposes will need to be changed for privacy concerns
        'rest_framework.permissions.AllowAny',
    ],
    'DEFAULT_AUTHENTICATION_CLASSES': [
        'rest_framework_simplejwt.authentication.JWTAuthentication',
    ],
}
```

I am making the request on the frontend in react via axios as follows:

```
const headers = { Authorization: 'Bearer ' + accesstoken};
        let res = await axios.post("http://localhost:8000/rest-auth/token/verify-access-token/",
           {headers}
        );
```

Comment: the token might have expired. By default, the DRF simplejwt token expires in 5min. Try with a fresh token.

Comment: Correct me if I'm wrong but when the user logs in here, they are given a fresh token (this is what RefreshToken.for_user in the GoogleView does to my understanding at least) , I am currently making the post from my frontend almost immediately after the login, hence I am making it with a fresh token so I don't think this is the issue, but thank you for your response

Comment: How do you get `accesstoken` for axios call here? `const headers = { Authorization: 'Bearer ' + accesstoken};` I think the issue might be somewhere here.